# how to handle 30x when using feedparser to parse rss url

Tags: python, feedparser

Now I am using Python 3 `feedparser` to parse some RSS url, this is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        feed = feedparser.parse("https://ucw.moe/feed/rss")
        print(feed.status)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

but I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use `requests` to get the feed before like:

```py
import requests
import feedparser

page = requests.get("https://ucw.moe/feed/rss")
print(page.status_code)
feed = feedparser.parse(page.content)
```